# With mocha-web-velocity, can you arrange some server-side code before running a client test?

Tags: javascript, meteor, mocha.js

I'm writing some clients tests using mocha-web-velocity, and am in need of running some server-side code before running a client test.

Is this doable? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, you can use Meteor.methods. Just make sure to put those under the mocha-web-velocity/server folder so they don't affect your original app code.

In the client tests, you can just call the server methods before the suites/tests.